# Python: difficulty in parsing file as JSON

Tags: python, json, open-json

I have uploaded a file [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoGbJ.png) that I am trying to parse as JSON, but my code below is not working:

```
with open('all_links_dict.json') as fd:
    json_data = json.load(fd)
    print(json_data)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: From what can be seen in that screen shot, you don't have a valid json file.

Comment: Wrap all the content in your file in {} to make it a valid JSON

Comment: I puted {}, but it did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a trailing ',' in the file, then it must also be removed. The following code tests if for the comma and removes it (later I will show you something simpler and better):

**Using `json`**

```py
import json

with open('all_links_dict.json') as fd:
    text = fd.read().strip()
    # Remove trailing ','
    if text[-1] == ',':
        text = text[:-1]
    json_data = json.loads('{' + text + '}')
    print(json_data)
```

**Using `ast.literal_eval`**

In this case we don't have to worry about a possible trailing ','.

```py
import ast

with open('all_links_dict.json') as fd:
    text = fd.read()
    data = ast.literal_eval('{' + text + '}')
    print(data)
```

**Update**

If the above code is still not working, you can find the offending lines with:

```py
import ast

with open('all_links_dict.json') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        try:
            data = ast.literal_eval('{' + line + '}')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Exception: {e}, line = {repr(line)}')
```

Comment: Instead of `'{' + text + '}'`, you can also use an f-string: `f'{{{text}}}'`.

Comment: Still dose not working.

Comment: You need to add a stack trace to your question. Also modify your file to just have a few keys and then rerun -- but be sure to edit your question to show us what the file looks like (no images -- format it as if it were code).

Comment: Also, see my update to my answer.

Comment: Did you ever find your problem?